# Queuing using RxJS Observables - Angular 5

Tags: angular, queue, rxjs, angular5, angular2-observables

I'm developing an SPA using Angular 5.

I have an scenario where I need to make multiple calls to a Rest API method, below is an example case.

I have a list of objects (say 100 objects) which will be passed as an parameter to API method. I need to queue the objects by picking the first 10 objects(async API  calls), if any of the call responds I need to push the next Object to the queue until all the 100 objects has been processed.

Is this possible to achieve technically. If yes could anyone advise how this can be achieved.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you always want to perform 10 request at a time. When one completes you want to immediately start another one.

Comment: @martin Thank u for your quick reply. It depends on the total number of objects I have. For an example I have mentioned 10 here

Comment: Ok, but when one completes you want to immediately start another one?

Comment: Yes add another one to queue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with just `mergeMap` that takes an optional second parameter that tells how many concurrent subscriptions you want it to keep (btw `concatMap` is just `mergeMap` with `1` concurency):

```
from([obj1, obj2, obj3, ..., obj100])
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(obj => makeHttpCall(obj), 10),
  )
  .subscribe(...);
```

This will always keep 10 HTTP call active. When one completes it'll pick another one immediately.

Comment: Thank you for your code snippet. Will try implementing it and will update you accordingly.